# Oracle DB, for each row delete any similar timestamps in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a program recording timestamps when users connect to a program. However sometimes it likes to record the same connections multiple times, so I'll have duplicate entries that are half a second apart or less. I need an oracle query that can essentially look at the timestamp in each row and delete rows with a timestamp that is within 5 seconds of it. I'm not sure what the best way to approach this problem is, but due to technical limitations I'm trying to avoid scripting it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Sample data looks something like this.

```
User, Timestamp
user1, 20-NOV-20 05.09.09.650146000 PM
user1, 20-NOV-20 05.09.11.764345432 PM
user2, 23-NOV-20 02.51.31.765432432 PM
user2, 23-NOV-20 02.51.32.355684235 PM
```

and I would want the query to trim it down to this.

```
user1, 20-NOV-20 05.09.09.650146000 PM
user2, 23-NOV-20 02.51.31.765432432 PM
```

If there were even more rows attributed to the same user close together it would get rid of them all. I imagine it would make look at each row and make a query to delete from UserSessions where timestamp <= (timestamp this row) + 5 seconds and timestamp >= (timestamp this row) - 5 seconds. But not where timestamp = (timestamp this row)

I have no idea what the syntax for this is or how do do the query per row.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. If there are five rows with 4 seconds in between each row, will you delete them excepted the first one? Else, which behavior your want in that case?

Comment: User, Timestamp
user1, 20-NOV-20 05.09.09.650146000 PM
user1, 20-NOV-20 05.09.11.764345432 PM
user2, 23-NOV-20 02.51.31.765432432 PM

Comment: I realized trying to post it here was a terrible idea and editted the original post.

Comment: Your statement " sometimes it likes to record the same connections multiple times, so I'll have duplicate entries" strongly suggests you have a bug in your program and rather than trying to locate and fix it, you are just looking to apply a band-aid.

Comment: It's actually an issue with Tableau Server's initial SQL function. And as much as I would like to, I don't think I can bug fix their code.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data and expected results would be helpful, particularly for various corner cases (several rows each within a few seconds of each other for example).  Assuming you want to keep the latest row, something like this would work

```
delete from your_table earlier
 where exists( select 1
                 from your_table later
                where earlier.user_id = later.user_id
                  and later.login_date > earlier.login_date
                  and later.login_date <= earlier.login_date + interval '5' second )
```

Here's a [liveSQL link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kzmpitekr245jvbpvm0d0rn1i) using your sample data that shows the query producing the results you expect.

Comment: I editted my initial post to include some sample data and the expected results.

Comment: @WestonSapusek - Then I think the query I posted is what you want.  Included a liveSQL link to show it working.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want to keep only rows where there is not a timestamp within 5 seconds before.  I think that would be:

```
delete from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                        t2.timetamp < t.timestamp and
                        t2.timestamp >= t.timestamp - interval '5' second
                 );
```